# Discordjs V14 not filtering while typing in for results. Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

i have tried using the following as the code to get a list.
[example 1](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/autocomplete.html#sending-results):

And i haven't had any success. With the example 1, i em getting the following (image) [image]
with example

When i type it [], anyone got an idea what im doing wrong here?

[Code](https://srcshare.io/64822bf7232de205c2686cc4) Line 19 - 35

Can't get the filter to display what matches to the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Array list to actually work, i didn't realize it was CaSe SeNsItIvE until recently. Sorry for wasting peoples reading time! Now to get it to be lower case so it doesn't have to be CaSe SeNsItIvE

```
    async autocomplete(interaction) {
    con.query('select typeName FROM invTypes JOIN invGroups ON invGroups.groupID=invTypes.groupID JOIN invMarketGroups ON invMarketGroups.marketGroupID = invTypes.marketGroupID and invGroups.categoryID = 6 AND invTypes.published  =1', function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        shipList(results)
    })
    async function shipList(results) {
        const list = results.map(list => list.typeName)
        const focusedValue = interaction.options.getFocused();
        const choices = list.filter(list => list);
        const filtered = choices.filter(choice => choice.startsWith(focusedValue));
        await interaction.respond(
            filtered.map(choice => ({ name: choice, value: choice })).slice(0, 25),
        );
    }
},
```